# change the default image name of an exe file started from .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have an exe file(from a console aplication) on trigerring which it will do diff jobs based on arguments passed to main.

Say if the argument passed is 1 then it will run handler "handler1".
If the argument passed is 2 then it will run handler "handler2"

I have a .bat file which will trigger this "batch.exe" file and thus starting some handler in vb application (i dont have any control to modify the code).

This bat file will be called at different times passsing diff arguments making the app to run diff handlers.

So at the start of every instance of **handler** (not just batch.exe), i want to check if the previous instance is running (if so then i need to kill the previous instance) and i need to do this from .bat file.

I know that we can do this from the .bat file using the TASKKILL or some equivalent commands and passing the "image name" (Here image name will be "batch.exe").

But the problem here is, all the handlers will be triggered by the same exe. so if i kill batch.exe it may kill other handler also.

so to achieve this, we need to give different names for different handlers while starting the exe file from batch code.

like
    if(argumetn passed == 1)
    {
    run batch.exe as 'handler1'
    }
    else if(argumetn passed == 2)
    {
    run batch.exe as 'handler2'
    }

so that i can kill handler1 or handler2 when ever required using taskkill?

Comment: The task is unclear.  If you show actual code and then explain it you may get better answers.

Comment: It sounds like you want to be able to launch a program and get its Pid so you can kill it later. Here is an example script to do that. [StartPid](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=5876#p5876)

Comment: @MattWilliamson - Thanks for your response. The second instance of the program should identify the first instance and kill it. The second instance may not have the pid of first instance. so this may not work for my scenario. intead of Pid if we can change the "image name"(i cannot use the default name, since there will be other handlers also running with the same name) then second instance can search all processes by that name and kill them.

Comment: Why don't you have your batch file `copy` the EXE to a new name before it runs it.  Each running instance would have a unique EXE name and you can be more selective with TaskKill by passing the modified EXE name (that is unique for each instance)?